# Ubuntu 11.04 stops booting at grub console

Tags: grub2

I did a fresh install of ubuntu 11.04, then I installed Windows 7. So I decided to fix the grub after win7 install using the ubuntu 11.04 Live CD.

Disaster:

instead of

```
$sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/media/uuid/ /dev/sda
```

I entered

```
$sudo grub-install --root-directory=/media/uuid/ /dev/sda
```

Now when my system boots, it stops at the grub console

```
grub>
```

My problem is exactly as this one http://aaron-kelley.net/blog/2011/04/grub-prompt-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-11-04/ but I have not been able to fix my problem. Thanx for your help.

Answer (score 8):

I never got in trouble by using these instructions:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Grub2#Recover

First of all, you must start your system from a live cd. Then

"**METHOD 3 - CHROOT**

This method of installation uses the chroot command to gain access to the broken system's files. Once the chroot command is issued, the LiveCD treats the broken system's / as its own. Commands run in a chroot environment will affect the broken systems filesystems and not those of the LiveCD.

**1)** Boot to the LiveCD Desktop (Ubuntu 9.10 or later). Please note that the Live CD must be the same as the system you are fixing - either 32-bit or 64-bit (if not then the chroot will fail).

**2)** Open a terminal (Applications > Accessories > Terminal).

**3)** Determine your normal system partition - (the switch is a lowercase "L")

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

If you aren't sure, run

```
df -Th
```

Look for the correct disk size and ext3 or ext4 format.

**4)** Mount your normal system partition:

Substitute the correct partition: sda1, sdb5, etc.

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXX /mnt
```

*Example: sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt*

**5)** Only if you have a separate boot partition:
sdYY is the /boot partition designation (for example sdb3)

```
sudo mount /dev/sdYY /mnt/boot
```

**6)**
Mount the critical virtual filesystems:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev  /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts  /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys  /mnt/sys
```

**7)**
Chroot into your normal system device:

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

**8)** If there is no /boot/grub/grub.cfg or it's not correct, create one using

```
update-grub
```

**9)**
Reinstall GRUB 2:

Substitute the correct device - sda, sdb, etc. Do not specify a partition number.

```
grub-install /dev/sdX
```

**10)** Verify the install (use the correct device, for example sda. Do not specify a partition):

```
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX
```

**11)**
Exit chroot: CTRL-D on keyboard

**12)**
Unmount virtual filesystems:

```
sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts
sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/sys
```

**13)**
If you mounted a separate /boot partition:

```
sudo umount /mnt/boot
```

**14)**
Unmount the LiveCD's /usr directory:

```
sudo umount /mnt/usr
```

**15)**
Unmount last device:

```
sudo umount /mnt
```

**16)**
Reboot.

```
sudo reboot
```

"

Comment: I get stuck at the `chroot` part

Comment: Which errors are showed to you?

Comment: `chroot failed to run command /bin/bash exec format error` Please help me.

Comment: Are you using a 64bit cd in  a 64bit installed system? (or a 32bit cd in a 32bit installed system). Make sure you are not using a 64bit cd in a 32bit installed system neither a 32bit cd in a 64bit installed system.

Comment: Yes I am using 64 bit cd or 64 bit system. Does the version of linux also affect this?

Comment: I think that it worth to try the same version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can solve this problem without using a LiveCD:

1. Search the root disk.

   `grub> search -f /vmlinuz -s root`
2. Set root disk.

   `grub> root ($root)`
3. Use these commands to find out root disk's information.

   `grub> ls -l ($root)`
4. Set linux kernel. There are three ways to do it.

   1. Change the red number with your root disk number. 
      If your root disk is `(hd0, msdos1)`, 
      then use `/dev/sda1` 
      `grub> linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1`
   2. Change red text with your disk label, which can get by using `ls -l 
      ($root)` 
      `grub> linux /vmlinuz root=LABEL=LABEL`
   3. Change red text with your disk uuid, which can also get by using `ls 
      ($root)` 
      `grub> linux /vmlinuz root=UUID=UUID`
5. Set ramdisk.

   `grub> initrd /initrd.img`
6. Now, you can boot your system.

   `grub> boot`
7. When you are logged in, type this command from terminal to fix your 
   grub menu.

   `$ sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve this, using the boot-repair program:

Boot with Ubuntu 11.04 Live CD and open terminal then copy and paste:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair-ubuntu
```

Then go to Applications -> System -> Boot Repair to run the program.

Comment: I used this program after several other methods had failed, and it did the trick.